# What is the latest WebSphere MQ Client version?

Tags: version, ibm-mq

I'm seeing downloads for 7.0.1.8 off the IBM website but at the same time I see 7.1.0.1 around. I do not see the download for the client of 7.1.0.1 though...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The WMQ clients are available as [SupportPacs](http://ibm.co/SupptPacs).  You can download one of the following:

- WMQ V7.0 Client == SupportPac MQC7 - **Withdrawn no longer supported**
- WMQ V7.1 Client == [SupportPac MQC71](http://ibm.co/SupptPacMQC71)
- WMQ V7.5 Client == [SupportPac MQC75](http://ibm.co/SupptPacMQC75)
- IBM MQ V8.0 Client == [SupportPac MQC8](http://www.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg24037500)
- IBM MQ V9.0 Client == [SupportPac MQC9](http://www.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg24042176)

Be sure to use the Knowledge Center for the version of client you are using!

- [WMQ V7.0.1 Knowledge Center](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_7.0.1/com.ibm.mq.helphome.v70.doc/WelcomePagev7r0.htm)
- [WMQ V7.1 Knowledge Center](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_7.1.0/com.ibm.mq.helphome.v71.doc/WelcomePagev7r1.htm)
- [WMQ V7.5 Knowledge Center](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_7.5.0/com.ibm.mq.helphome.v75.doc/WelcomePagev7r5.htm)
- [WMQ V8.0 Knowledge Center](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.helphome.v80.doc/WelcomePagev8r0.htm)
- [WMQ V9.0 Knowledge Center](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_9.0.0/com.ibm.mq.helphome.v90.doc/WelcomePagev9r0.htm)

Comment: Updated with links to v7.5 client and Infocenter.

Comment: Updated with links to v8 client and Knowledge center

Comment: Updated with links to v9 client and Knowledge center.  Link for v7.0 client was no longer valid and I could not find a current link since it has been withdrawn and out of support, noted this as well.  Also updated 7.0 - 7.5 to current Knowledge center links.