# Configuring mq websphere 7 with .net

Tags: c#, .net, websphere, ibm-mq

I am trying to connect to a remote queue using c#. 
I tried many ways to connect to the remote queue but it always fails with common errors like: `MQRC_CHANNEL_CONFIG_ERROR` or `MQRC_HOST_NOT_AVAILABLE`.

What I am doing is this:

```
        string channel = "QM_TEST.SVRCONN"; 
        string hostname = "<serverIp>"; 
        string queueName = "QM_TEST"; 
        string port = 1414; 

        props.Add(MQC.HOST_NAME_PROPERTY, hostname); 
        props.Add(MQC.CHANNEL_PROPERTY, channel); 
        props.Add(MQC.PORT_PROPERTY, port ); 
        props.Add(MQC.TRANSPORT_PROPERTY, MQC.TRANSPORT_MQSERIES_MANAGED); 

        MQQueueManager mqQueue = new MQQueueManager(queueName, props);
```

I have tried changing this but all failed.

I think that my problem is the server configurations.. 
can you point me to a full guide to how to configure a server and connect to it with .net?

My problem is connecting to a REMOTE server using .net and not to a local server.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that the CCSID between the client and the server were different.

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.mq.csqzaf.doc%2Fcs12480_.htm

On the client side I had to put

```
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("MQCCSID", "437");
```

Thats why I got:

```
MQRC_CHANNEL_CONFIG_ERROR
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing the problem (or at least *a* problem) is here:

```
MQQueue mqQueue = new MQQueueManager(queueName, props);
```

This should be

```
queueManager = new MQQueueManager(queueManagerName, properties);
```

If you have installed the WebSphere MQ client to the default location, there are many sample programs under the following directory:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere MQ\tools\dotnet\samples\cs\base\
```

There are a number of sample programs there for various tasks.  If you have the latest V7.1 client installed then you will see the following programs:

```
SimpleAsyncPut
SimpleClientAutoReconnectGet
SimpleClientAutoReconnectPut
SimpleGet
SimpleMessageProperties
SimplePublish
SimplePut
SimpleReadAhead
SimpleSharingConversation
SimpleSubscribe
SimpleXAGet
SimpleXAPut
```

There are also WCF and XMS samples.

If you need the client code, please see my response to another SO question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10957612/what-is-the-latest-websphere-mq-client-version/10957643#10957643) for links.

**Update:**

Here's the normal diagnostic process.

1. If the WMQ components were installed by relocating libraries or classes from somewhere else, perform an install using the full vendor-supplied client media.  This includes troubleshooting utilities such as trace, dspmqver, etc.  It also resolves any library or class mismatch issues.
2. Use the pre-compiled client programs to test the connection.  The `amqsputc`, `amqsgetc` and `amqsbcgc` programs require the `MQSERVER` environment variable [as described here](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r1/topic/com.ibm.mq.doc/cs12280_.htm).  The Q program from [SupportPac MA01](http://ibm.co/SupptPacMA01) is a separate download but has the advantage of NOT requiring any environment variables, CCDT files or other dependencies.
3. If the sample programs fail, check the QMgr's error logs at `[WMQ install]/qmgrs/[QMgr name]/errors/AMQERR01.LOG` for messages.  Also check for FDC files and errors in `[WMQ install]/errors`.
4. If no errors on the QMgr side, attempt the connection again while using a client-side trace as described [here](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r1/topic/com.ibm.mq.msc.doc/xms_ctrouble_trace_net.html) and [here](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r1/topic/com.ibm.mq.doc/cs12880_.htm).

Most client problems are resolved through installation of the full WMQ client as supplied by IBM. (Conversely that implies most people are installing by grabbing DLL or JAR files.)  If the problem persists, error log inspection on the QMgr and client side usually reveals the underlying cause.  If these do not work then tracing usually diagnoses the remaining issues.

**UPDATE 2:**
Per the error messages [posted at MQSeries.net](http://www.mqseries.net/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?p=332547#332547), the channel has a security exit set.  A security exit is external code that the channel calls out to when starting a channel.  There is no way to know what the exit expects or does without having access to the code or docs of the exit.  If the exit is written in-house, you'll need to talk to the programmer to figure out what it requires. If the exit is a commercial product then you will need to get the documentation for it.

Alternatively, alter the channel so that `SCYEXIT` is blank to disable the exit.

The data posted at MQSeries.net was as follows:

```
MQ9575: DCE Security: failed to get the user's login name.

EXPLANATION:

System call 192.168.50.55 to get the login name of the user running WebSphere
MQ client application process 5 failed with error value -1. This occurred in
security exit function create_cred. The exit will now attempt to open channel
using the DCE default login context.
ACTION:
If you wish to run using the DCE default login context take no action. If you
wish to run using the user's login name as the DCE security exit principal
examine the documentation for the operating system on which you are running MQ
clients and reconfigure the operating system as necessary to allow the
192.168.50.55 call to succeed.
```

Note that it states the call is failing in the security exit.

Comment: sorry about the typing error I just copied parts of the code.
I don't believe its a code error because when I used the samples and the console of mq it still doesn't work.
It gives me: MQRC_CHANNEL_CONFIG_ERROR 

how should I configure the server?

Comment: How did you install the .Net classes?  If they were installed with a WMQ Server, it is necessary to select the WMQ client components during the install. Also, the QMgr must have the channel specified and a running listener on the port specified. You can test this using the `amqsputc` program in `C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere MQ\tools\c\Samples\Bin`.  You can also test using the Q program from SupportPac MA01 http://ibm.co/SupptPacMA01  If these work then you have a code issue.  If not then its a config issue.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help.
It still doesn't work with the same error - CONFIG_ERROR

**What config error can it be?**
I saw that MQRC_CHANNEL_CONFIG_ERROR 
is [one of these](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.mq.amqzao.doc%2Ffm20910_.htm) but how do I solve these problems? and how do I know which one is it..

Comment: When you say "it still doesn't work" I don't know what "it" is.  The .Net code?  Did you try using the pre-compiled, stand-alone Q program from SupportPac MA01 and is that what is now giving you the errors? Since Q takes all necessary parms from the command line, it eliminates issues such as client.ini file, environment vars or code problems. If that gives you the errors then usually it's a QMgr or client installation issue. I'm about to leave for an international flight. I'll check back when I can. Hopefully, Shashi will sign on soon and join the conversation.

Comment: Hi, yes I did try it with q.
I really think it is a configuration error on the server side because one my local computer I am able to connect and add messages to a queue.

I Get this errors in the queue manager server side:

AMQ9575: DCE Security: failed to get the user's login name.