# MQ jar compatible with Maven for IVY

Tags: maven, ivy, ibm-mq

My current task in the company is to implement IVY dependency management.
Now I hit the following libraries that I couldn't find in usual Maven repositories, such as http://mvnrepository.com:

com.ibm.mq.jar

com.ibm.mq.pcf.jar
...

and so forth (they are all with the prefix: com.ibm.mq).

I could found them on a separated website: http://www.java2s.com/
But it's not Maven compatible.

So, where could I found those? What's the best solution to overcome this?

I'm thinking, uploading them manually to the team nexus. But is this the usual procedure in such cases?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Best place to find those is directly from IBM.  Please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10957612/what-is-the-latest-websphere-mq-client-version/10957643#10957643) for the different versions of the WMQ Java/JMS client available.

As for the best way to package these, please be aware that if you want IBM to support them you need to install the client code rather than just bundling in the jar files. The reason IBM is reluctant to support non-standard installs should concern you as well if the app is to be installed in Production.  The full client includes considerable additional functionality such as diagnostics, trace functions, crypto libs, JSSE, etc. In addition, it is the only install against which you can apply IBM's maintenance.

If you install the jars from a 3rd party site such as the one linked above, do you even know what version they are? Has any of the maintenance been applied? Have the latest patches been applied? Since IBM only distributes the full client, and OEMs are not authorized to distribute the jar files except as part of their application, any site offering the WMQ jar files is by definition pirating them.

I realize that requiring you to do the full client install is considered burdensome when you are used to being able to just grab some jars and go. On the other hand, if you don't need support then you might install the WMQ Client on a VM somewhere, keep it up to date and grab the jar files from there. That way you have a known-good set of files that are all in sync and to which you can [apply maintenance](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?rs=171&uid=swg27006037).

If you'd like to suggest to IBM that they need a lighter-weight Java solution, feel free to raise the requirement (or vote on it if it already exists) at the [IBM Request For Enhancement (RFE) Community](http://ibm.co/P5TVP3).

Comment: Thank you. The question was at the beginning just a .jar download, turned out to be an IBM software practice. I will raise this issue with my team. Thanks again.

Comment: So why don't IBM creates its own repository? Then we can only add this in our pom files. Now the only way to solve this issue is to have our own repo on Nexus and upload artifacts manually. It just 90's style, don't you think?

Comment: Click the link at the bottom of my answer and tell IBM about it directly. If enough people want the feature, they'll add it.

Comment: I already did that a couple months ago... :) but lets don't get our hopes down! Viva la revolution!

Comment: Here: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rfe/execute?use_case=viewRfe&CR_ID=42559
Add comments or vote or something. Downloading the whole MQ Client (220MB) just to extract some jar files just drives me crazy!!!