# What is the latest version of MQ API and what is its compatibility with different operating systems?

Tags: java, ibm-mq

I currently use very old version (1.3.0) of MQ API (com.ibm.mq.jar) in my project. I want to upgrade to latest MQ API. When serached on Google, I came to know that it was initially called MQSeries, later renamed to WebSphere MQ and now renamed it to IBM MQ. With the answer on similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10957612/what-is-the-latest-websphere-mq-client-version), I got to know that latest version of IBM MQ client is 8.0.

I have very little exposure on IBM MQ and I am curious to know following:

1. One can get all the .jar files for specific version of MQ API with the corressponding MQ client version, right? i.e. once I install any client, there is "\java\lib" folder in which it has all required .jar files.
2. What are the improvements in MQ API 8.0 over 7.5?
3. Is Message Queue Interface just another name of MQ API?
4. Can the same set of .jar files of any particular version e.g. 8.0 be used in Java application that run on Windows and Linux? Or is there different set of .jar files for Linux version?
5. I saw two varients for IBM MQ client 8.0 - x64 and x86. When tried to install x86 on my Windows7 x64 OS, it gave me an error. That is ok and I understood that these are OS specific versions. But I would like to know compatibility of .jar files (MQ API) which I get from IBM MQ client 8.0 x64 with the following:

   *Are these .jar files compatible on x86 OS?*

   *Are these .jar files    compatible with JDK7 x86?*

I am interested in WebSphere MQ classes for Java and not WebSphere MQ classes for Java Message Service. I am using JDK7u79 on Windows7.

I would really appreciate if any expert can comment on above points. Thanks.

Comment: For starters, please hover over the [tag:websphere-mq] tag or click it, then select info.  About half of these questions are answered directly already there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MQ API doesn't have a version number itself, the product (MQSeries / WebSphere MQ / IBM MQ) has the version number which defines what is in the MQ API for that version of the product. I'm not 100% sure what your quoted version number is applicable to since there isn't a V1.3 of the product. It sounds like a Java version perhaps?

To answer your explicit question:-

1. Yes, the correct jars for the release of the MQ Client you are using come with it and these are the ones you must use.
2. There were very few, if any, changes to the MQ API in V8.0 over V7.5. There were certainly many other function changes to IBM MQ V8.0, it's just that they did not require extensions/changes to the MQ API. You can see an overview of the changes in IBM MQ V8.0 [here](http://www.slideshare.net/MoragHughson/whats-new-in-ibm-messaging/25).
3. Message Queue Interface (MQI) is the name of the procedural MQ API, used by languages such a the 'C' language or COBOL. There are also OO classes such as for Java or .NET and JMS classes.
4. Since the jar files come with the client you install, you should just use the ones that came with the client on Windows, or the client on Linux. As of v8.0 there is a supported pure-Java installation consisting of just the jar files.  Details are available at [this Technote](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21683398).  Use this client if the intent is to install jar files only.  To make sure it is supported, install as per IBM's instructions.
5. Again, this question suggests you are planning to move the jars around. If you use the ones that come with the client install you will be fine. @Calanais may be able to answer these last two Java related questions better than me.

Comment: @Calanais can you also take a look at this one please?